# MinGW lost boost files

Tags: windows, boost, mingw, boost-geometry

I've installed boost-1.68.0 under windows into "C:\boost". When I try to compile simple program using boost/geometry.hpp, mingw throws an error:

```
fatal error: boost/geometry.hpp: No such file or directory
```

I've tried this:

```
g++ example.cpp -o example.exe -I"C:\boost\include\boost-1_68" -L"C:\boost\lib"
```

Answer (score 0):

It appeared that installation of boost was not completed properly despite of the fact that no errors was showed during the process.
There were no *.hpp files in "C:\boost\include" directory, just the structure of empty folders.
The problem was solved by manually coping same boost folder with *.hpp from downloaded install package.